# Does this length refer to wavelength or length?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, photons, laser

In this question:

> A He-Ne laser emits red light of the wave length $\lambda = 632.8\ \mathrm{nm}$ with a beam diameter of $2.0\ \mathrm{mm}$ and a power output of $1.0\ \mathrm{mW}$ [...] (d) How many photons are there in the $1\ \mathrm{m}$ long laser beam?

In part (d) I am not sure if the $1\ \mathrm{m}$ here is referring to the wavelength or the length. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: What @JohnRennie said is true, but I would note there _is_ a conceptual question here. I've edited to make it clear. That doesn't _necessarily_ make the question on topic, since our homework policy does have two requirements, ask a conceptual question _and_ show an appropriate amount of effort.

Comment: @Mew please don't post answers in the comment section

Comment: @DavidZ, nevertheless I've converted my comment to an answer.

Comment: @Mew you can let him know yourself (as you did). It's easy to forget sometimes, even for high-rep users.

Comment: Seems to me this is more related to reading comprehension than physics (and I mean no offense by this, just that it should be clear what the wavelength is since it's explicitly stated).

Answer (score 2):

Total length. The wavelength is already provided as 632.8nm.